# files not uploading when there more than 1 seperate file upload fields

Tags: angularjs

Can some tell me why doesnt my selected files are not been passed through AngularJS and captured by PHP?

I am using this plugin to handle https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

when a i do a `var_dump($_FILES)` it always shows as empty

**HTML**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
 <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="subject" required>
  </div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" class="form-control" ngf-select="" ng-model="cv" required>
 </div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" class="form-control" ngf-select="" ng-model="photo" required>
 </div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" class="form-control" ngf-select="" ng-model="voice" required>
 </div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="sendfiles(cv,photp,voice)">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('uploadApp', ['ngFileUpload']);

var appCtrl= [ '$scope', 'Upload', function($scope, Upload) {

  $scope.sendfiles= function(file1,file2,file3) {

Upload.upload({
    url: 'uploading.php', 
    method: 'POST',
    file: [file1,file2,file3],
    data: {
        'subject': $scope.subject,
         }
      })

  };
}];
```

Comment: Check the example link of `ng-file-upload` for multiple file upload, http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/huhjo9jm/5/

Comment: I don't see `ngf-select` appearing in any of your HTML tags.  How can the directive work then?

Comment: @Fissio i did check that, but that's one input for multiple selects, what what im trying is to have 3 separate selects which passes different values

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen oh.. I missed that. Let me add that and see

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i added `ngf-select=""` but still the `var_dump($_FILES)` is empty